# Indexeddb Error Unknown but code is working

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am new to this so please let me know how I can improve my questions.

I have a fair-sized JSON obj that I'm trying to store to the HDD to retrieve later. The code is working and functional for quite some time - then just (what appears to be at random) throws an error:

> UnknownError: The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the
> database itself and not covered by any other error code.

I've seen other SO questions that point to this - the they seem to be specific to the browser or some odd setting? I'm using Visual Studio Code and Firefox.

This is the code I have in place (which works perfectly). After a few dozen loads while I'm working on this page - it will throw the error above and will not load at all. I need to clear all the data in the local DB for it to work again.

```
openDB:function(action, save_game_name){
    var indexedDB=window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB ||   window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB,
    
        // OPEN DB OR CREATE NEW BASED ON VER (NAME, VER)
        request=indexedDB.open('GAMESDB', 1);
    
        // UNCOMMENT TO DELETE DATABASE
        //var request=indexedDB.deleteDatabase('GAMESDB');  
    
    // CREATE DATABASE FOR FIRST TIME
    request.onupgradeneeded=function(){
        GAME.REF.DB=request.result;
        GAME.REF.STORE=GAME.REF.DB.createObjectStore('SaveGames', { keyPath: 'saveName' });
    };

    // DATABASE SUCCESSFULLY OPENED
    request.onsuccess=function(){
        // START NEW TRANSACTION
        GAME.REF.DB=request.result;
        GAME.REF.TX=GAME.REF.DB.transaction('SaveGames', 'readwrite');
        GAME.REF.STORE=GAME.REF.TX.objectStore('SaveGames');

        //>> DATABASE ACTION
        switch(action){
            //>> LOADING DATA
            case 'load':
                var LOADED=GAME.REF.STORE.getAll();

                LOADED.onsuccess=function(){
                    // LOOP SAVEGAME SAVEDATA
                    for(var i=0; i<this.result.length; i++){
                        // OVERWRITE LAUNCH GAME.DATA VARs
                        if(this.result[i]['saveName']===save_game_name){ 
                            GAME.DATA=this.result[i].saveDATA;
                        };
                        // POPULATE SAVEGAME NAMES
                        GAME.OBJ.$Save.find('input.GAME_SaveInput')[i].value=this.result[i].saveName;
                    };

                    // UPDATE URL
                    var href=window.location.href;
                    window.history.pushState(false, '', href.substring(0, href.lastIndexOf('?')));                                      
                };
            break;

            //>> SAVING DATA
            case 'save': 
                var SAVED=GAME.REF.STORE.put({'saveName': save_game_name, 'saveDATA':GAME.DATA}); 
                SAVED.onsucces=function(){ console.log("SAVED")}; break;

            //>> DELETE SAVEGAME
            case 'delete': GAME.REF.STORE.delete(save_game_name); break;

            //>> POPULATE SAVEGAMES
            case 'populate': 
                // PULL RECORDS FROM DB
                var records=GAME.REF.STORE.getAll();
                records.onsuccess=function(){
                    // LOOP RECORDS TO GET SAVEGAME NAMES           
                    for(var i=0; i<this.result.length; i++){
                        GAME.OBJ.$Save.find('input.GAME_SaveInput')[i].value=this.result[i].saveName;
                    };
                };
            break;          
        };

        // CLOSE THE DB WHEN TRANSACTION IS DONE
        GAME.REF.DB.onerror=function(e){ console.log('Error: '+ e.target.error); };
        GAME.REF.TX.oncomplete=function(){ 
            GAME.REF.DB.close(); 
        };      
    }
```